# Cubic spline or polynomial interpolation of non strictly increasing x in Scilab

Tags: interpolation, spline, scilab, cubic-spline

I have a set of xy points:

```
x = [1 2 3 3 2]
y = [1 1 2 3 2]
```

[image: plot of the points]

I would like to do an interpolation of those point. My issue is, [interp1()](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/interp1.html) or [splin()](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/splin.html) require a strictly ecreasing x.

How can I get an interpolation like this:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5]
y = [1 1 2 3 2]
xx = linspace(1, 5, 100);
yy2 = interp1(x, y, xx, 'spline');
plot(xx',yy2)
scatter(x, y)
```

[image: interp1 interpolation plot]

**But with a non increasing x ?**

I do not only need the plot, but also get the interpolation value for a given x and y.

Comment: You have duplicate values of x with different y value. Do you want to approximate you data in the least square sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parametric curve, you have to consider a third vector `t` (the values of the parameter) and compute two splines. You can change the spline type by changing the third parameter (see the `splin` help page):

```
x = [1 2 3 3 2];
y = [1 1 2 3 2];
t = 1:5;
dx = splin(t,x,"natural");
dy = splin(t,x,"natural");
tt=linspace(t(1),t($),1000);
plot(interp(tt,t,x,dx),interp(tt,t,y,dy),x,y,'o')
```

[image]